# Adapting set up of data in R

Tags: r, matrix

Often I am working with data from the Dutch Central Bureau of Statistics (CBS). Their data is in my opinion not very script friendly. I always need to manually adapt the data a lot before I can get it on my maps. Which is what I do, I am a Geo Information Scientist.

Today I started to script in order to adapt the data I get from the CBS and convert it in my datafile. So far I have been doing this manually. Today I remembered why. I find it quite hard to work with this data. Levels and factors are bugging me often. I do not need more literature about that, I am trying to learn why and when it is wrong.

I have data that looks like:

```
municipality name         first data col    second data col    third data col    etc.
2004
2005
2006
2007
2008
othermunicipality name
2004
2005
2006
2007
2008
Etcetera
```

What I want is something like:

```
              Municipality name                           Other municipality name
years         first data col    second data col    etc.   first data col    second data col    etc. 
2004
2005
2006
2007
2008
```

I understand I can not expect a whole script as a response. But I think I need a boost in the right direction at the moment. How should I approach this situation?

Is it even possible to work with a double column name? A name of a municipality, and then the name of the data itself.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to just have a lot of dataframes/matrices. One for each municipality which I can relate to a list of years and grab the data of the year I want out.

Comment: When you say "data row", do you by any chance mean data column? I would read in with `readLines`, mark the breakpoints with `grepl` and then `split` on `cumsum(breakpoints)`

Comment: You are right, I have adapted it. Thank you for the advice. Going to check out your comment into deep tomorrow.

Comment: Are these csv files? Is there any other information in the row that has "othermunicipality name"?

Comment: They are downloadable in multiple formats. I take the csv format indeed. Under 'other municipality name' there are multiple columns with data.

Answer (score 0):

This answer sort of copies my response to a previous question. The way I do double column names in R is by using 'reshape' which will separate names by a period. As for parsing the data to populate the municipality name column based on column 1 which is obviously the first step, I may jump back on this later but I'm a bit busy at present and this gives you a starting point at least.

```
#example code
 a <- c(rep(1:10, 3))
 b <- c(rep("aa", 10), rep("bb", 10), rep("cc", 10))
 set.seed(123)
 c <- sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50, by = 5), size = 30, replace = TRUE)
 d <- data.frame(a,b, c)
 #how to rename it#
 e<-reshape(d,idvar='a',timevar='b',direction='wide')
 e
```